# Using Jquery, call function on selection just once

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say i have a selection of textboxes like this;

```
var arrayoftextboxes = $('.textbox1, .textbox2, .textbox3');
```

Is there a way I can call a function on each one in a simpler way than this?
It only needs to be called once.

```
arrayoftextboxes.each(function(i){foo(arrayoftextboxes[i]);});
```

I tried

```
arrayoftextboxes.load(function(){foo(this)});
```

and

```
arrayoftextboxes.bind(function(){foo(this)});
```

but the functions dont seem to be called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$('.textbox1, .textbox2, .textbox3').each(function() { foo(this); });
```

The [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) call creates a closure, inside it `this` refers to the DOM element you're currently on, but it may be better to write what you have as a [jQuery plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring).  Or, if you just use `this` inside `foo` (instead of the DOM element as a parameter) you can shorten it down to:

```
$('.textbox1, .textbox2, .textbox3').each(foo);
```

[Here's a demonstration of that method](http://jsfiddle.net/YhnLV/)

Also, make sure you're running this on `document.ready` like this:

```
$(function() {
  $('.textbox1, .textbox2, .textbox3').each(foo);
});
```

Otherwise the DOM elements may not be there to find, making that selector return an empty array (so nothing to run on).